# Application returns different results to sql-server management studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I have an application which grabs some data with the following sql:

```
SELECT Sum(fieldname)          AS fieldNameHere,
   Sum(Cast(error AS INT))  AS Error,
   Sum(jsperror)            AS JSPError,
   Sum(linkerror)       AS LinkError
FROM   schemaname.sessiondata session
WHERE  starttime >= :startTime0
   AND starttime < :endTime0
   AND fieldname = :fieldNameVal0
UNION ALL
SELECT Sum(fieldname)          AS fieldNameHere,
   Sum(Cast(error AS INT))  AS Error,
   Sum(jsperror)            AS JSPError,
   Sum(linkerror)       AS LinkError
FROM   schemaname.sessiondata session
WHERE  starttime >= :startTime1
   AND starttime < :endTime1
   AND fieldname = :fieldNameVal1
UNION ALL
SELECT Sum(fieldname)          AS fieldNameHere,
   Sum(Cast(error AS INT))  AS Error,
   Sum(jsperror)            AS JSPError,
   Sum(linkerror)       AS LinkError
FROM   schemaname.sessiondata session
WHERE  starttime >= :startTime2
   AND starttime < :endTime2
   AND fieldname = :fieldNameVal2
```

Debugging and examining the code the parameter values are:

```
startTime0=Wed Sep 12 22:00:00 BST 2012
endTime0=Wed Sep 12 23:00:00 BST 2012
hitPrices0=1 
startTime1=Wed Sep 12 23:00:00 BST 2012
endTime1=Thu Sep 13 00:00:00 BST 2012
hitPrices1=1
startTime2=Thu Sep 13 00:00:00 BST 2012
endTime2=Thu Sep 13 01:00:00 BST 2012 
hitPrices2=1
```

Then running the following SQL in SQL-server management studio provides the correct data:

```
SELECT Sum(fieldname)          AS fieldNameHere,
   Sum(Cast(error AS INT))  AS Error,
   Sum(jsperror)            AS JSPError,
   Sum(linkerror)       AS LinkError
FROM   schemaname.sessiondata session
WHERE  starttime >= '2012-09-12 22:00:00'
   AND starttime < '2012-09-12 23:00:00'
   AND fieldname = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT Sum(fieldname)          AS fieldNameHere,
   Sum(Cast(error AS INT))  AS Error,
   Sum(jsperror)            AS JSPError,
   Sum(linkerror)       AS LinkError
FROM   schemaname.sessiondata session
WHERE  starttime >= '2012-09-12 23:00:00'
   AND starttime < '2012-09-13 00:00:00'
   AND fieldname = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT Sum(fieldname)          AS fieldNameHere,
   Sum(Cast(error AS INT))  AS Error,
   Sum(jsperror)            AS JSPError,
   Sum(linkerror)       AS LinkError
FROM   schemaname.sessiondata session
WHERE  starttime >= '2012-09-13 00:00:00'
   AND starttime < '2012-09-13 01:00:00'
   AND fieldname = 1
```

Note: this is not a mistake with startDate and endDate, the parameters are different from the fields. startDate and end date parameters represent the startdatetime and enddatetime of that paticular interval. the startDate field represents the session start time.

The incorrect results returned in the app:

```
[null, null, null, null]
[2, 1, 0, 0]
[null, null, null, null]
```

and the correct results from sqlsms:

```
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

I cannot work out why this is?

Comment: I know you are saying it's not a mistake with the date, but I'm very sure it's. The only way you can get different sets running this on your application and in the management studio is by having different inputs.

Comment: Time zone issues? There's a "BST" in the times you got from the application...

Comment: Is the application in the same server (so it's getting the same time)? Is the application using the same time zone?

Comment: The time of the server should be irelevant. I am looking up values from the DB. Time zone was a consideration, but either side of the one that is causing the error is correct in both.

Comment: different inputs - yes, thats possible, but its only in the way that hibernate is interpreting the Java Date object into SQL, which i cannot tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that formatting the date object and passing as a string to set the parameter on the SQL fixed this problem.